# Formatting Numbers with PHP

Tags: php, number-formatting

I'm saving numbers in MySQL using double(10,2).

The numbers are getting saved like:

456.2

232.20

764

On output, I want to force 2 decimals and add the necessary trailing zeros (currency).

Here is the function I'm using and it isn't working.

```
function format_currency_form($get_money) {

    $money_output = abs(number_format($get_money, 2, '.', ''));

    return $money_output;
}
```

(I'm using ABS because I want the value to display as a positive number regardless of its true value in the db)

Here is the code block used to output the data:

```
<?php echo format_currency_form($row_rs_data['trans_amount']); ?>
```

No errors getting thrown and no trailing zeros...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Brett

Comment: After some more testing, if I remove abs(), it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with currency try to use moneyformat

http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

money_format('%.2n', $number)

In your case the abs should be done in this way:

```
$number=-11.44;
$money_output = money_format('%.2n', abs($number));
echo $money_output;
```

If you are dealing with currencies (I think so) money_format gives you a lot of options.

Comment: `money_format()` should not be used because it was deprecated in PHP7.4 and removed in PHP8 https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) to output formatted strings.

```
echo sprintf("%.2f", format_currency_form($blah_blah));
```

Comment: Just wanted to add for clarification that `%.2f` means a float value with 2 digits past the decimal. `sprintf` and other formatting functions when used in this way will add trailing zeroes to force the string to match the specification. `764` becomes `764.00`, `764.2` becomes `764.20`, etc.

Comment: This worked, even with using the abs() function, where my initial function did not nor did the money_format. Not sure why though.

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.